# CSS блок поверх всего контента

Tags: html, css

Есть блок с краю экрана небольшой. При наведении он расширяется. Проблема в том, что он "выезжает" не поверх моего контента, а под него. Точнее только под картинки (скриптовые банеры с прокруткой и тп.) Можно ли сделать так, что бы он выезжал поверх всего? CSS:

```
  div.nav  {    
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        right:6px;
        top: 80%;
        display:block;
        height:160px;
        width:33px;
        background:url(../img/helpback.jpg) no-repeat;        
        line-height:50px;
        transition:all .7s ease-out;
        border: 1px solid #333;
        border-radius: 2em;
    }

    div.nav:hover {
        position: fixed;
        right: 5px;
        top: 80%;
        width:347px;
        height:160px;  
        display: block;        
    }
```

Comment: @OlegShleif, не стоит изменять код в вопросах(кроме форматирования, если оно не является синтаксически значимым), порой подобные "опечатки" и являются причиной возникновения проблемы.

Comment: Я изучил вопрос, и данная 'ошибка' совсем не к месту, а куча пользователей которые ещё не сильно знакомы со стилями могут скопировать себе не совсем верный код. Поэтому было принято решение на изменение. Но, как я понял, вы видите это с иной стороны

Comment: а есть ещё варианты кроме z-index? в случае если такое позицинирование не подходит..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Добавьте правилу `div.nav` свойство `z-index: 999999;`

Строго говоря, ваш элемент должен иметь значение `z-index` большее, чем положение по z-оси других элементов страницы, т. е. и значения `z-index: 100;` может быть достаточно

Comment: не обязательно такой большой ставить :)

Answer (score 3):

```
div.nav:hover {
        position: fixed;
        right: 5px;
        top: 80%;
        width:347px;
        height:160px;  
        display: block;
        z-index:99999999;        
    }
```